# Need help to solve query (using datepart)

Tags: sql, advantage-database-server

```
SELECT
  -- Subtract minute, second, millisecond part of date, effectively rounding to floor of the hour
  -- For example '2017-03-17T14:31:25.567' becomes '2017-03-17T14:00:00.000'
  DATEADD(
    mi, -1 * (DATEPART(mi, tab.logindt) % 60),
    DATEADD(
      ss, -1 * (DATEPART(ss, tab.logindt)),
      DATEADD(
        ms, -1 * (DATEPART(ms, tab.logindt)),
        tab.logindt
  )))      AS "Date",
  COUNT(*) AS "Count"
FROM TableName tab
WHERE
  tab.logindt BETWEEN 'Dec 1 2009 12:00 AM' AND 'Dec 2 2009 23:59 PM'            
GROUP BY
  DATEADD(
    mi, -1 * (DATEPART(mi, tab.logindt) % 60),
    DATEADD(
      ss, -1 * (DATEPART(ss, tab.logindt)),
      DATEADD(
        ms, -1 * (DATEPART(ms, tab.logindt)),
        tab.logindt
  )))
```

---

We have an application in which a number of people login, the problem is I want to make a query through which I can count number of people logged in to the system at a particular time say 10 am/11/12/14.

Above query have made using datepart, through which i can check number of people signed at say 10 am OR sign out.

For example above query returns 10 people sign/signout at 10 am but it does not show me people who are currently using system.

Answer (score 0):

Find all login/logout events before 10am and filter those such that max(login) > max(logout).

```
SELECT COUNT * FROM 
(SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE login < 10am //your date function here!
and logout < 10am ) a
GROUP BY a.USER
HAVING MAX(a.login) > MAX(a.logout)
```

Something like that perhaps?